# October cms rtl style

Tags: right-to-left, octobercms

i work on website with two css stylesheet [style.css and style-rtl.css]
how to make octobercms change the stylesheet when choosing a rtl language from localePicker in front end?

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate

```
<p>
Switch language to:
<a href="#" data-request="onSwitchLocale" data-request-data="locale: 'en'">English</a>,
<a href="#" data-request="onSwitchLocale" data-request-data="locale: 'ru'">Russian</a>
```

with like this in the layout css part(replace with css path):

```
{{ 'site.name'|_ }}

{{ 'Welcome to our website!'|_ }}

{{ 'Hello :name!'|_({ name: 'Friend' }) }}
```

look dokumetation from: http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate